# What do the input and output "languages" for the -x flag in GCC mean?

Tags: gcc, compiler-options

I am trying to compile a piece of code that was previously compiled with gfortran in ifort instead.  The old compile line has a `-xf95-cpp-input` option in it that doesn't make sense to me.

Looking in the GCC docs, it seems like the `-x` option tells the compiler to ignore the file extension of the source code file, and parse it explicitly with the language you tell it to.  So for example, I could run `gfortran -xf77 myfunkycode.lulwut` and it will parse my `.lulwut` file as an f77 file.

This makes sense, but then what does `f95-cpp-input` or `c++-cpp-output` mean?  What do 'input' and 'output' even mean in this context?  I'm guessing "input" is the source code?  "Output" is the object file?  According to the docs, `-x` is just for choosing the "language of the input file," why is 'output' in the language list at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> f95-cpp-input

Compile the source file as f95 file *with cpp preprocessor*.

> c++-cpp-output

Compile the source file as C++ file *without cpp preprocessor*.

> What do 'input' and 'output' even mean in this context?

Just a convention I guess.

Comment: So generally, "lang1-lang2-input" means "lang1 with lang2 preprocessor" and "lang1-lang2-output" means "lang1 without lang2 preprocessor"?  For "c++-cpp-output" what is it doing for the preprocessor, just using C?  Or no preprocessor?

Comment: For that matter, what's the difference between "c++-cpp-output" and "cpp-output"?

Comment: My guess is `cpp-output` is C source file without cpp. `c++-cpp-output` is a C++ source file without cpp. Seems to check out - `printf "%s\n" "#define a main" "int a() {}" | gcc -x cpp-output -` fails with undefined main - `#` are comments.

Comment: `So generally,` No idea, it makes no sense to me, I would just learn the options by heart. `For "c++-cpp-output" what is it doing for the preprocessor, just using C?` It compiles the file as C++ without running the preprocessor. There is no C involved. `Or no preprocessor?` Literally, yes.

Comment: when you say it as "without cpp preprocessor" the first place my mind goes is "well, I guess you could use a different preprocessor" since you didn't say "without any preprocessing."  Compiling without any preprocessor step just strikes me as bizarre and alien.

Comment: `Compiling without any preprocessor step just strikes me as bizarre and alien` Really? Compiling is famously done in 4 stages, source file -> preprocessing (cpp) -> compiling (gcc) -> machine code (assembler, also gcc) -> linker (ld) -> output. It's just without the cpp step.

Comment: Right, 4 stages not three.  I can't imagine why you'd want to skip the preprocessing stage.

Comment: @Frank - it's necessary when you have a build process that looks like: `gcc -E` (run the preprocessor on a file)-> then run some tool or filter that changes the code further -> `gcc -x cpp-output`.  Basically it means "this file has already been through the preprocessor once, so just run the compiler and later stages on it."